# Is there a Integer class in c#?

Tags: java, c#

We have `Integer` class in JAVA, but I couldn't find any equivalent class in C#? Does c# have any equivalent? If not, how do I get JAVA `Integer` class behavior in c#?

**Why do I need this?**

It is because I'm trying to migrate JAVA code to c# code. If there is an equivalent way, then code migration would be easier. To addon, I need to store references of the `Integer` and I don't think I can create reference of `int` or `Int32`.

Comment: Looking for [`System.Int32`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx) structure?

Comment: What behaviour are you after?

Comment: Can't quite tell if this is a joke question... What have you researched?

Comment: Is this a joke? Or do you have a specific behaviour which you are after, but cannot find?

Comment: Basically I moved from JAVA to c#. So, I wanted similar behavior for easier migration of code.

Comment: @SonerGönül Not really looking for `Int32`. As it doesn't have constructor :|. I'm trying to migrate JAVA code to C# and using `Int32` struct might not be useful in easier migration.

Comment: @Abhishek - C# is *not* Java, and identical code may not always be the right way to go anyway.  You should add an example to your question that shows *specifically* what you are asking, as well as what you have tried/researched

Comment: @Sayse I understand JAVA and c# aren't same. But I had requirement of code migration. Hence asked. Edited question accordingly.

Comment: What behavior are you looking for? Your question is unclear / too broad. @Kenneth Clark, even though this is a C# question it is about Java behaviour so the Java tag is relevant

Comment: As someone that works in the industry of code transposition, I can tell you that you are looking for the wrong thing. don't make the mistake of looking at the code from a syntactical point of view, look at the code from a logical point of view. This will save you a lot of time and effort.

Comment: @ZoharPeled got it. I thought OOP would be nicer and more readable. but it looks, I'm wrong :)

Comment: @Abhishek: `Int32` *does* have a constructor.  Try this: `new Int32()`

Comment: @Abhishek you don't _need_ a constructor. Just use the `=` operator, as in `Int32 i = 5;`.

Comment: @recursive `Int32` doesn't have constructors with the same functionality as `Integer`

Comment: @pcluddite yup, using it as of now :)

Comment: I think this is a great question, especially for someone trying to understand C#. Since `Integer` objects can be null in Java, perhaps a nullable type would do: `int?`. Nullable types are references.

Comment: @ZoharPeled - OP says *I need to store references of the Integer* - that is a design feature, not a syntactic feature. I occasionally encounter the same design need in c#, and wish there were such a standard class, instead of having to roll my own.

Comment: You can always pass variables around explicitly by ref if you choose to. What exactly is it that you cannot do?

Comment: @Theo You cannot store an int reference in a collection, modify that, and **have everyone who is holding that reference see the change**.  [He needs `int?`, but all the downvotes, and off-purpose responses, indicate people are knee-jerk reacting to his desire to have an int class, and missing why he may actually need a class.  The correct response is "use `int?` if you need to **store** it **as a reference**, otherwise you can simply do `ref myIntValue` when you pass as a parameter."

Comment: @Theo and just in case this isn't clear to anyone else coming along: If someone is already "holding a reference", and needs to see any changes that you make independently, then a class (here, `int?`) is the solution. This is no different than any other situations that need a class. Otherwise, we wouldn't have the concept class. We would only need `struct`. Of course, you can always make your own wrapper class. But that would be clumsy.

Comment: I have had occasion to pass int's to functions by ref which solves some of the issue, I had not considered the implications of adding the int to a collection then modifying the value in the collection, that would put a "copy" rather than a ref in the collection - hence the problem. I agree, defining it as an `int?` should solve the problem since `Nullable<T>` is a class and will pass by ref.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve - perhaps my test is flawed, but it appears `nullable` is a struct and does NOT pass by ref, so you still have a similar problem. Looks like the solution is to "roll-your-own" generic reference class to wrap simple types like int's.

Comment: @Theo - thanks for testing that. I see that you are right. If a reference type is needed, we have to make our own custom class :(

Comment: Yea - I threw my "failed" nullable test below and the successful revision. I think @Abhishek 's question should get some up-votes - made me look and think hard!

Answer (score 17):

C# has a unified type system, so `int` can be implicitly boxed into an `object` reference.  The only reason `Integer` exists in Java is so that it can be converted to an object reference and stored in references to be used in other container classes.

Since C# can do that without another type, there's no corresponding class to `Integer`.

Comment: For me at least, this is not the only reason. I use Integer is a nullable int. It's useful to know when a property is unset. Because of autoboxing and unboxing it feels pretty much like a unified type system.

Comment: @StevePaul `int?` stores a nullable integer without the need for boxing and it is the standard usage.

Comment: All I was saying is that Integer can be used just like int?. That is more often the reason I use them in Java.

Comment: Your answer is off-the-mark: the fact that an `int` value can be boxed into an object doesn't help a programmer who needs a reference type (needs a change in one place to be seen by all other referrers). There is no "Integer reference" class built in to c#. Even `int?` doesn't solve this.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve:  I cannot imagine any practical use case for a reference type wrapper for integers.  How can the number 7 be mutated?  The only state it has is its identity.  If you change the number, it's just another number, not the same number with different properties.  Numbers should be immutable, like strings.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: Additionally, the question is asking about porting from Java.  Java does have an `Integer` wrapper, but it is immutable, meaning no state can be changed, so even if someone did find a scenario requiring a mutable integer, it can't apply to this question.

Comment: And generics supports primitive types in C#.

Comment: "Since C# can do that without another type, there's no corresponding class to Integer." This is false, C# does have an internal `Integer` wrapper class, otherwise `new object[] {42}` would not be possible, it is just not exposed.

Comment: I find immutable numbers a rather huge performance issue when doing reports of many thousands of numbers that involve totals and other math functions. Ends up creating hundreds of thousands of needless objects. But maybe I'm missing something, I'd love to hear otherwise.

Comment: @DavidBradley: The thing that you're missing is that in .net, "normal" numbers (like `int`, `long`, `short`, `double`, and `float`) aren't reference values.  Using thousands of numbers doesn't create any objects at all, because, as an implementation detail, numbers are not objects.  Calculating a number does no allocate, and creates no garbage collector pressure.

Comment: @recursive yes true in C# for primatives, I was thinking in general. For instance Java has an immutable BIgDecimal which for reports creates a lot of needless objects.

Answer (score 6):

Code migration won´t work out of the box for any type of language without any manual changes. There are things such as a class `Integer` that simply does not exist within (C# why should it anyway, see recursives answer), so you´d have to do some work on your own. The nearest equivalent to what you´re after is `Int32` or its alias `int`. However you may of course write your own wrapper-class:

```
    public class Integer
    {
        public int Value { get; set; }


        public Integer() { }
        public Integer( int value ) { Value = value; }


        // Custom cast from "int":
        public static implicit operator Integer( Int32 x ) { return new Integer( x ); }

        // Custom cast to "int":
        public static implicit operator Int32( Integer x ) { return x.Value; }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return string.Format( "Integer({0})", Value );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why would you need to write your own Integer class when Int32 does the exact same thing?

Comment: Obviously the OP does not want to replace all of his occurences of `new Integer()` by C#-code, so this constructor ensures that his code may work exactly the same.

Comment: This only adds a layer of inefficiency. C# is not Java. The OP needs to rewrite the code in a way suited for the language.

Comment: @PCLuddite - because Int32 *is not a reference type*, it is a structure. You can't *store a reference to an integer* using it. An "integer reference class" works like this:  `Integer a.Value = 5; Integer b = a; b.Value = 3; if (a.Value == 3) ..` the if test returns `true`; changing b's value also changes a.

Comment: @HimBromBeere - I would add two constructors. `public Integer() {}` and `public Integer(int value){ Value = value; }`   Adding as an edit; hope you don't mind.

Comment: @PCLuddite the need for reference-typed integers must not be that great or Microsoft would have made them reference types rather than value types, however if you DO need a reference type int, this is an option as to how it can be achieved.

Comment: @Theo Not only is the need not that great, but it would cause issues with boxing/unboxing like you see in java. The unified type system makes generics a lot easier to work with and you don't have to deal with conversions between primitives/objects.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve use the `ref` keyword if you have to. If you need it to be `null`, use a nullable. You don't paint the Mona Lisa with a hammer. You can't even do what you described in java because `Integer` is immutable.

Comment: @PCLuddite I'd need to see an example of the boxing/unboxing issues you are referring to, but the reason for this approach is to allow primitives to be added to collections by reference and still have the original value remain a reference value - that is not possible by simply passing by ref (see my sample below). Seems like an extremely niche need - but there it is.

Comment: @Theo I was referring to java's implementation of generics, which uses type erasure. [This is a good explanation of the issues with it](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generics_in_Java#Problems_with_type_erasure).

Comment: C# has to have an internal `Integer` class as a wrapper for `Int32`, otherwise this: `new object[] {42}` would not be possible, shame that is it not exposed and we have to write our own.
Why do I need this? I need to bind integer ID to objects, `ConditionalWeakTable` seems perfect, except the key needs to be a class, not a struct.

Comment: @kajacx That does not mean there´s an `Integer`-class, but just that any value-type can be **converted** to `object`, which we call boxing.

Answer (score 2):

The beauty of C# is that it has a unified type system. Everything derives from `object`, even primitive types. Because of this, all keywords are simply aliases for a corresponding class or struct. Java does not use a unified type system, so a separate `Integer` class is required to wrap the `int` primitive. In C# `int` is synonym for the `Int32` struct.

What you're looking for has been right in front of you the whole time. Start using the dot notation directly on the `int` keyword  (i.e. `int.whatever()`) to access the all goodness of the .NET version of the Javian `Integer` class.

Comment: Doesn't help if OP actually does need a reference type. `int` or `Int32` *is not a reference type*. You can't *store a reference to an integer* using it. An "integer reference class" works like this:  `Integer a.Value = 5; Integer b = a; b.Value = 3; if (a.Value == 3) ..` the if test returns `true`; changing b's value also changes a.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve The OP didn't mention reference types in the original question. I answered what was asked at the time. Why would you need a reference type? I can't think of any situation where that would be useful in a unified type system.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve: That's not related to this question though.  This question is about a replacement for java's `Integer` class, which is immutable, and also doesn't support that use case.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve it's a moot point anyway since this is asking about mimicking Java functionality in c#, and the Java Integer class is immutable. So the OP quite obviously does *not* require this.

Answer (score 2):

I did some testing with Nullable types in a console application and it appears that they do not behave as you wish. For example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int? x = 1;
    Foo(ref x);
    Console.WriteLine(x);//Writes 2
}

private static void Foo(ref int? y)
{
    y += 1;
    var l = new List<int?>();
    l.Add(y);
    l[0] += 1;//This does not affect the value of x devlared in Main
    Console.WriteLine(l[0]);//Writes 3
    Console.WriteLine(y);//writes 2
    Foo2(l);
}

private static void Foo2(List<int?> l)
{
    l[0] += 1;
    Console.WriteLine(l[0]);//writes 4
}
```

But if you roll your own generic class to wrap primitive/value types for use within your application you can get the behavior you are expecting:

```
public class MyType<T>
{
    public T Value { get; set; }
    public MyType() : this(default(T))
    {}
    public MyType(T val)
    {
        Value = val;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Value.ToString();
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var x = new MyType<int>(1);
    Foo(x);
    Console.WriteLine(x);//Writes 4
}

private static void Foo(MyType<int> y)
{
    y.Value += 1;
    var l = new List<MyType<int>>();
    l.Add(y);
    l[0].Value += 1;//This does affect the value of x devlared in Main
    Console.WriteLine(l[0]);//Writes 3
    Console.WriteLine(y);//writes 3
    Foo2(l);
}

private static void Foo2(List<MyType<int>> l)
{
    l[0].Value += 1;
    Console.WriteLine(l[0]);//writes 4
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what some answerers/commenters/downvoters-of-the-question missed. Sometimes, the program design really *does* require a reference type (multiple locations holding a reference; all locations see a change made at any location). C# lacks a built-in equivalent to each value type, forcing us to write our own. Which seems silly. The case I ran into was a dictionary <OurKey, int>. At first, I could make it work with coding that used "ref" parameter passing. Then hit a situation where I needed to STORE a *reference* elsewhere to one of those dictionary values. Oops.

Comment: .. The moral I got out of this situation was that I should have gone with my initial instinct:  I knew that conceptually I should be storing some reference instance. I tried to use the built-in `int`, because that was less initial work. And I hate cluttering my project with hundreds of little classes. After this experience, I will be hesitant to ever again use a value type as the type of a collection value.

Comment: BTW, I've enhanced [HimBromBeere's earlier answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30296951/199364) to be a good, complete example of a wrapper class for Integer. Unfortunately, that can't be generalized to `<T>`, as you have nicely done here, if one wants to include the static conversion operators.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve you're probably doing something wrong or have an incredibly niche usage if you require a reference type to an int. Ints are cheep and it's generally better and faster to copy than to create a pointer to (aka a class) in any language like this.

Answer (score 1):

int, int? and System.Int32 are all struct and thus value types and does not compare to Java's Integer wrapper class which is a reference type.

System.Object class though a reference type can cause issue as boxing creates immutable object. In short, you can't alter a boxed value.

```
        int a = 20;
        Object objA = a; //Boxes a value type into a reference type, objA now points to boxed [20]
        Object objB = objA; //Both objA & objB points to boxed [20]
        objA = 40; //While objB points to boxed [20], objA points to a new boxed [40]
        //Thus, it creates another ref type boxing a 40 value integer value type, 
        //Boxed values are immutable like string and above code does not alter value of previous boxed value [20]
        Console.WriteLine($"objA = {objA}, objB={objB}");
        //Output: objA = 40, objB=20
```

What exactly corresponds to Java's Integer is a custom generic wrapper class.

```
        int a = 20;
        Wrapper<int> wrapA = new Wrapper<int>(a);
        Wrapper<int> wrapB = wrapA; //both wrapA and wrapB are pointing to [20]
        wrapA.Value = 40; //Changing actual value which both wrapA and wrapB are pointing to
        Console.WriteLine($"wrapA = {wrapA}, wrapB={wrapB}");
        //Output: wrapA = 40, wrapB=40
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Implementation of the wrapper class is given below:

```
public class Wrapper<T> where T : struct
{
    public static implicit operator T(Wrapper<T> w)
    {
        return w.Value;
    }

    public Wrapper(T t)
    {
        _t = t;
    }

    public T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return _t;
        }

        set
        {
            _t = value;
        }
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return _t.ToString();
    }

    private T _t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in other answers, C# has a unified type system so everything derives from `object`. If you need to handle `null` values then use `int?` to specify that the integer object can be `null`.

Answer (score -2):

c# have a integer type called int link is here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5kzh1b5w.aspx